# php - server side include broken pictures

Tags: php, backend, ssi

when I add an include to my header, i get broken photos.

example:

[image]

my code:

```
<?php virtual('includes/nav.php'); ?>
```

is there a problem in my code?

html:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">PLAY</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://fb.com/officialninjaa"><img src="../images/facebook.png" width="60" height="17" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://twitter.com/martinshamasha"><img src="../images/twitter.png" width="64" height="17" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try `src="/images/twitter.png"` etc.

Comment: That's an simple clue, that your source is not correct. Try the absolute path.

Comment: Does `/images/twitter.png` exist on your server?

Comment: Do you really need to include your nav.php file with the `virtual()` function? What happens if you try `include()` instead?

Comment: The browser only downloads what you've told it to download. Right click the images and inspect the URLs you've provided. Understand then the issue, try to understand the cause and learn about URLs, you will need that more than once.

Answer (score 2):

`virtual()` performs an Apache sub-request, which causes URLs to be relative to the directory of the resource being accessed by that sub-request. So here:

```
<img src="../images/facebook.png" width="60" height="17" />
```

Since `virtual()` is executing 'includes/nav.php', the image's src attribute is pointing to 'images/facebook.png' relative to the original URL (not '../images/facebook.png').

To avoid confusion like this, try using absolute URLs instead of relative URLs:

```
<img src="/docroot/path/to/images/facebook.png" width="60" height="17" />
```

For your reference here is the official documentation on this function: [virtual()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php)

Comment: thanks. i fixed the path but it doesnt work when i upload it on my localhost server @chjohasbrouck

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the source of the image to the root

```
/images/facebook.png
```

Comment: ok the images worked, the issue was the path but when i upload it on my localhost server it wont display the photos.